# Formatting decimal places in Java

Tags: java, formatting, double, decimal

I'm trying to format a double to just 2 decimal places in Java.

I've read the following post:
[How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

For some reason, every one of those methods fails to work on certain numbers I have..

For example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
normalizedValue = Double.valueOf(df.format(normalizedValue));
```

If I print `normalizedValue` I get result similar to the following:

```
-78.64000000000001

18.97

59.469999999999985

-63.120000000000005
```

(Note: some are formatted correctly... some aren't)

So, these methods seem to round, but I need something that will remove all decimals after 2 decimal places... Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The string representation given by `DecimalFormat.format(...)` does indeed have only 2 digits in your example. But as soon as you reconvert it into a double those accuracy issues occur. A binary base format like double will always show such effects when you try to represent "exakt" decimal fractions. You may change to `BigDecimal` to get rid of such effects.